# Python, Tk and OptionMenu: how to sort a drop down list?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I want to make a drop down list with tk and OptionMenu. I want to show a string to the user ("10 us", "40 us"...) and return a number (0, 1,...) which is a parameter that I send to a variable. It works well, but it's not sorted. I want to sort the list like the variable "lst1".

[image]

It should be:

- 10 us
- 20 us
- 40 us
- 80 us

  ```
  lst1 = {"10 us": 0,
          "20 us": 1,
          "40 us": 2,
          "80 us": 3,
          "160 us": 4,
          "320 us": 5,
          "640 us": 6,
          "1.28 ms": 7,
          "2.56 ms": 8,
          "5.12 ms": 9,
          "10.24 ms": 10}
  var_tc = StringVar()
  var_tc.set("40 us")
  list_tc = OptionMenu(frame, var_tc, *lst1.keys())
  list_tc.config(takefocus=1)
  list_tc.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=2, pady=10)

  param.tc = lst1[var_tc.get()]
  ```

Could you help me, please? :)

Comment: sort the keys, or use an ordered dictionary

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that you're using a dictionary as a list, and dictionaries don't have any notion of order. Two ways you could do it; both are pretty straightforward.

## Way 1: Just use sorted keys

You don't have to change much, just when you pass in `lst1.keys()`, you instead pass in `sorted(lst1.keys())`, since `keys()` returns a list and you can give a sorted one of those.

## Way 2: Use a dictionary that keeps order

One of the python standard libraries is `collections`, which contains many containers of varying usefulness. One of these is the `OrderedDict`, a dictionary that keeps the order in which you enter things. You would import it as `from collections import OrderedDict`, and initialize it as any other object - `lst1 = OrderedDict([("10us",0), ("20us",1), ...])`